# Calling/accessing static variables or methods

Tags: object, static, instance

I am studying for the OCA and this code was in the book I am using.

```
 public class Koala {
       public **static** int count = 0;
       public **static** void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(count);
       }
    }

    Koala k = new Koala();
    System.out.println(k.count); //prints 0
    k = null;
    System.out.println(k.count); //prints 0
```

I understand that when a static variable changes in one object it changes in all of them. Why doesn't this last println print "null"?!

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that when a static variable changes in one object it changes in all of them

You understand incorrectly. That is, you are incorrect to think of a static variable as being *"in one object"* in the first place.

The static variable is not a member of an instance of the class at all. In some languages (such as Java, which is what you appear to be using here), you can access static members through variables having the same type of the class. But you aren't accessing an instance of the class in that case. You're still accessing the *shared* variable that is really part of the *type* of the class, not any individual instance of that class.

More idiomatically, one would actually write `Koala.count` to access the `count` field in your example.

When you write e.g. in your code something like `k.count`, the value of `k` isn't relevant at all. It's a quirk of the language that the compiler interprets the whole expression to refer to the same member that the expression `Koala.count` refers to. I.e. since there is no need to dereference an instance reference to access the `count` member, it's considered legal to do so through any variable having the type `Koala`, even if the current value of that variable is `null`. The `null` is ignored, since no reference of any instance is required at all to access the static member `count`.

Since the value of the variable `k` is ignored, you get the same result whether it's assigned to an actual instance of the class `Koala`, or is simply `null`.

Comment: Yeah i actually read some where that k.count changes to koala.count after compilation. So k is null, but count is not...? I think I understand now. The only thing I didnt  get was when you said "part of the type" of the class.

Comment: @timothy: The "type of the class" is `Koala`. The `count` field is a member of that type, i.e. a member of `Koala`. Granted, non-static members are, in some real sense, also a member of `Koala`, but in a much more practical sense they are really a member of each _instance_ of `Koala`, while static members are _just_ a member of `Koala` itself. Static members aren't really members of each instance, even though you can refer to them through `Koala`-typed variables.